# Prove that A Vector-Valued Function with Convex Components is Convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$ are convex. Prove that the vector valued function $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is convex.

I can't seem to figure this one out no matter how hard I try. Here's my attempt.

Need to show: $(1): f(\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$.

Since $f_1(x)$ is convex, we have:
$f_1(\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f_1(x)+(1-\lambda)f_1(y)$

Since $f_2(x)$ is convex, we have:
$f_2(\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f_2(x)+(1-\lambda)f_2(y)$

Now starting with the left-hand side of $(1)$, we have:
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y)&=(f_1(\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y),f_2(\lambda(x)+(1-\lambda)y))\\
&\leq (\lambda f_1(x)+(1-\lambda)f_1(y),\lambda f_2(x)+(1-\lambda)f_2(y))\\
&=(\lambda f_{1}(x), \lambda f_2(x))+((1-\lambda)f_1(y), ((1-\lambda) f_2(y))\\
&=\lambda (f_1(x), f_2(x))+(1-\lambda)(f_1(y),f_2(y))\\
&=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)
\end{align*}
I'm not sure if the second step where I have the inequality is correct, I use the convexity of $f_1$ and $f_2$ . Overall, I'm just not very confident. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's the definition of convexity for functions with values in $\mathbb R^2$ ? What order do you set on $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure @Gabriel Romon. I'm trying to prove convex monotone superposition:https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_3.pdf . The author (pg. 60) says "and due to the convexity of the components of $f$ we have $f(\lambda x + (1 − \lambda)x^{′}) ≤ \lambda z + (1 − \lambda)z^{′}$", so I try to prove above that a vector-valued function with convex components is convex. is my proof incorrect?

Comment: It's not standard to use the term "convex" to describe a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$. But the proof you gave is correct, as long as we agree that the inequality is interpreted componentwise.

Comment: No, the author proves that if $F:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is convex and monotone (in a way he defines), and $f_1, f_2:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ are convex, then $x\mapsto F(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is convex.

Comment: @Gabriel Romon, he states that $f$ is convex since its components are convex. I want to prove this fact since its not obvious

Comment: @GabrielRomon He defines $f(x)=(f_{1}(x),....f_{k}(x))$ where $f_{1}(x)$,....$f_{k}(x)$ are all convex. He then states on pg. 60: "due to the convexity of the components of $f$ we have $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) x^{'}) \leq \lambda z +(1-\lambda) z^{'}$ where $z=f(x), z'=f(x^{'})$ implying that $f$ is convex. I want to show that such a $f$ is convex.

Comment: The author never uses the term "convex" to describe $f$, and that would not be standard terminology.

Comment: @littleO Just to make sure in Page 60 of https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_3.pdf . The author defines $f(x)=(f_{1}(x),....f_{k}(x))$ where $f_{1}(x)$,....$f_{k}(x)$ are all convex. He then states on pg. 60: "due to the convexity of the components of $f$ we have $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) x^{'}) \leq \lambda z +(1-\lambda) z^{'}$" where $z=f(x), z'=f(x^{'})$ implying that $f$ is convex. he doesn't prove this fact, he just states by the convexity of the components of $f$. does my proof work for proving this fact (where k=2)? thanks

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct, but I think it's probably better not to use the term "convex" to describe $f$.

Comment: @littleO I see. So in my own proof, can i just say that $f$ satsifies the inequality I proved in my original question without calling f convex. In other words, is the inequality in my proof correct and the justifications of the steps in my proof correct. I just need the inequality, I don't necessarily need to call f convex. thanks

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Your proof is good.

Comment: thanks for the help and clarifications @little0

Comment: and @Gabriel Romon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer the question: the proof you gave is correct. (But it's not standard to describe a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ as "convex".)

Comment: and just to be completely sure, my proof shows the inequality given in page 60 of https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_3.pdf, (in the case k=2)? thanks.

Comment: where the inequality that he has is: $f(\lambda x+ (1-\lambda) x^{*}) \leq \lambda z +(1-\lambda) z^{'}$, where $z=f(x), z^{'}=f(x^{'})$? thanks and sorry for all the questions

Comment: @BoyWonder Yes, that's correct. What you call $y$, they call $x'$.